# How to get data from blogger feeds with $.getJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to get data from blogger feeds [link](http://test-khamsat-support-gig.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default/-/Break?max-results=10&orderby=published&alt=json-in-script&callback=lp) with $.getJSON function and I use this code to get the version but it doesn't work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[[
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON('http://test-khamsat-support-gig.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default/-/Break?max-results=10&orderby=published&alt=json-in-script&callback=lp',function(data){
        alert(data.responseText.version);
    });
  });
//]]>
</script>
```

Comment: [It's just `data.version`](http://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/GJ2MM/).

Comment: I think the problem is that the server which you are trying to access does not allow it. Check your console, I get the following message: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'file://' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: The returned data is JSONP which is handled by `$.getJSON` by adding a callback to the URL like the OP has done, so I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: @Andy I use your first seggestion but no luck

Comment: @ilokhov because you try test the code outside of my [blog](http://test-khamsat-support-gig.blogspot.com/)

Comment: Thank you guys for your time, Finally I solve the problem with $.get()